# Axway Desktop Validator

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008, smartcard

I have a windows server 2008R2 set up, we recently updated our servers personal certs and did a network reboot. Everything was fine for a few days until our weekly network reboot took place and from then on all users get an error 'Smart card login is not supported on your account'. We checked ADUC and all users are set up to require smart card to login. In event viewer on our DC we see that there is an error in Tumbleweed under Microsoft that says "The description for Event ID 16 from source Desktop Validator cannot be found. Either the component that raises the event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer."

Our desktop validator is functional however, we can download CRLs and can open our webpage for Axway and see that no CRLs are expired. Any ideas why smart card login is not supported.

Comment: Did you get an answer to your issue? Having similar problem with Axway Desktop Validator.

Comment: Yes, it turns out that one of our admins downloaded the cert as a server certificate instead of a Domain Certificate so the function for KDC was not on the certificate thus not enabling smart card login. If you get the functions of the certificate you will see what it has and if it does not have KDC then you won't be able to use tokens